# Create custom Map for Highmaps using Shapefiles and QGIS

Tags: highcharts, qgis, highmaps

I try to create a custom Map with Highcharts – I need german job center districts. I've done it the way it is described [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps).
I imported the shapefiles to QGIS an created a highcharts map [here](https://www.highcharts.com/studies/map-from-svg.htm).
 But on this way, all information like the name oft he district got lost. Is there a way to keep it? Because there are a lot of districts – I don't want to write all single names by my own.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to generate GeoJSON from the provided shapefile (the one that you provided me with via email) and place it in the JSFiddle boilerplate (http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/xbzxfx2L/). Empty map displayed without any problems. To add values to the regions and also to display data labels you need to add adequate data and link it to the `mapData` (more about it in the API link below). I have prepared an example for you. Simply, copy the content of created GeoJSON (generated from the shapefile using QGIS, as described here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps) to the textarea and click run button. The map with the values should show up. Also, you could try to use map of Germany from our maps collection. It can be found here: http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.joinBy

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/w20e8vja/